# AngularJs (1.5+) dynamic binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are developing our own library of AngularJs (1.6.x) components/directives and we would like to have all HTML attributes that are specified on our components automatically and dynamically passed on to the underlying templates, **without having to specify every single attribute as a binding**.

For example, if I have a component like `<my-component>` with a template like `<div class="my-component"></div>` and I write in my HTML:

`<my-component ng-required="ctrl.isRequired" ng-change="ctrl.onChange()" ng-attr-disabled="ctrl.isReadOnly"></my-component>`

I want my template to render:

`<div class="my-component" ng-required="ctrl.isRequired" ng-change="ctrl.onChange()" ng-attr-disabled="ctrl.isReadOnly"></div>`

As I said above, we cannot know in advance all attributes, so they can't all be defined in the component bindings. The problem gets more complicated in Angular 1.5+, because `replace` has been deprecated, so the above template would render something like this:

```
<my-component ng-required="ctrl.isRequired" ng-change="ctrl.onChange()" ng-attr-disabled="ctrl.isReadOnly">
    <div class="my-component" ng-required="ctrl.isRequired" ng-change="ctrl.onChange()" ng-attr-disabled="ctrl.isReadOnly"></div>
</my-component>
```

And also, when we have nested, deep hierarchies of components, we want the values to be passed down from the parent controllers to the (grand)children, i.e. the `ctrl.onChange()` method will be defined in the scope of the page controller where `<my-component>` is defined, but as each component in the hierarchy gets its own scope, as you go deeper, we want the method to still be callable.

I am relatively new to Angular, I hope the above make sense.

Comment: _"I hope the above make sense"_ Not to me. I can't imagine a use case where copying properties makes sense. What do you want to achieve? You are new to Angular, so you might be missing something.

Comment: "I hope the above make sense." - Not really ... at all ... Please try to provide a deeper situation of your problems / goals.

Comment: I don't know how to describe my use case better. Our components need to have a small, fixed set of attribute bindings, but the rest of the attributes (i.e. the ones not explicitly bound) should just be passed on. Setting whether this is good practice aside, is it technically feasible?